# Why is my write() not working?

Tags: javascript

For learning purposes I'm building a simple messaging program that I think can work with local storage. Another question about 2 dimensional arrays is in the comments.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
    <html>     
        <head>             
            <title>waGwan?</title>     
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <link rel=stylesheet href=comm.css></link>       
        </head>     
            <body>                              
                <section>
                    <p>enter or create passcode: <input type=text id=passcode></p>
                    <input type=button id="button" value="send">
                </section>
                <section id="log"></section>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    //initializing my passcode. Pass is a two dimensional array that holds passcodes and arrays of corresponding message logs; how can I instantiate my passcode without nil but maintain pass as a two dimensional array, just not include pass?
                    var pass=[mypasscode,nil];
                    document.getElementById("button").onclick=checkPass;
                    function checkPass(){
                        for(i=0;i<pass.length;i++){
                            //exits if passcode exists
                            if(document.getElementById("passcode").value==pass[i]){
                                break;
                            }
                            //if passcode doesn't equal last existing passcode the passcode and a new array (that stores the message log) is added to the pass array
                            else if(document.getElementById("passcode").value!==pass[pass.length-1]){
                                pass.push(document.getElementById("passcode").value,[We can chat here.]);
                            }
                        }
                        document.write("x");
                    }
                </script>
            </body> 
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  pass.push(document.getElementById("passcode").value,[We can chat here.]);

                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                        here is the problem
```

try this

```
pass.push(document.getElementById("passcode").value,["We can chat here."]);
```

you can use ide like neatbean which will warn you it there is any error like below

[image]

Comment: Still doesn't work in chrome. Do you like netbeans as a javascript ide, what about the mozzila one.. firbug or something? Thanks!

Comment: @user1656125 You should ask clear questions in your post instead of asking them in the comments of the code. You can instantiate the array as: "var pass = [mypasscode, []];" and your syntax error is because your are missing the quotes in the array: "['We can chat here.']"

Answer (score 0):

You had a few errors. Such as

`pass.push(document.getElementById("passcode").value,[We can chat here.]);`

`[We can chat here.]` is not valid.

and these vars in that you put into the array when you initialize it are not declared.

```
 var pass=[mypasscode,nil];
```

I recommend you hit f12 if you are using Chrome or IE and look at the script portion so you can better debug your issues.

Try the following, which works, although may not be exactly what you were trying to do.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/GvGQ8/)**

```
   //initializing my passcode. Pass is a two dimensional array that holds passcodes and arrays of corresponding message logs; how can I instantiate my passcode without nil but maintain pass as a two dimensional array, just not include pass?
                    var pass=["mypasscode","nil"];
                    document.getElementById("button").onclick=checkPass;
                    function checkPass(){
                        for(i=0;i<pass.length;i++){
                            //exits if passcode exists
                            if(document.getElementById("passcode").value==pass[i]){
                                break;
                            }
                            //if passcode doesn't equal last existing passcode the passcode and a new array (that stores the message log) is added to the pass array
                            else if(document.getElementById("passcode").value!==pass[pass.length-1]){
                                pass.push(document.getElementById("passcode").value);
                            }
                        }
                        document.write("x");
                    }​
```

Comment: I was trying to add an array to the pass array. Pass is supposed to be a two dimensional array that holds passcodes and arrays.